# File Download using PHP/Apache2 and Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, download, apache2

The download method I am using:

- I have a "Export" button in HTML which when clicked sends some data to the server.
- The server processes the data, writes the CSV to a file and whether the writing was successful or not, sends an appropriate JSON message.
- On receiving a success message, I do a `window.open` with the proper url and attached file name to start the download.
- The download **happens** on Firefox in Ubuntu 15.04 alright as well as IE 11 on Windows 7.

However the download **fails** on Google Chrome 45.0.2454.85 m on Windows 7. It just opens a new blank window and then nothing happens. I have browser cache cleared. What is the right way to start a file download for Chrome?

Here is the PHP code responsible for the download.

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". basename($filename));
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-Length: ". filesize($filename));
ob_clean();
flush();
readFile($filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try write all your headers after ob_clean().
ob_clean() clear all data with headers.